# Making hover features compatible with mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, hover

So i have developed a website and created a feature where when you hover over a box it reveals text however when i tested my website on mobile you cant hover do there being no cursor and it doesn't recognise clicks if i was to click the box so how can i make it compatible so that if on a mobile it works the same just with a click etc

```
    .container .box .content{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}


.container .box:hover .content{
    top: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.container .box .content h3{
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.container .box .content p{
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

[This is how it looks on website when i hover over a box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Y5t.png)

any help is much appreciated

Comment: try using media queries with `:focus` Psudo element

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

> Hovers aren't possible on mobile devices as there is no persistent
>   cursor - memory of the last touched point by default.

The only way they can sense interaction is touch, which is akin to a click or selection, so `:active` in `CSS` or `onclick` in `Javascript` are your only options currently.

There you go use `:focus` and `:active` as well along with `:hover`

```
.container .box:hover .content,
.container .box:focus .content,
.container .box:active .content{
    top: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

> :focus represents the state when the element is currently selected to
>   receive input and
>
> :active represents the state when the element is  currently being activated by the user

Ref links
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Answer (score 0):

This question is more about **UI/UX** for mobile state,
and the reason is you **can't hover** on top of element in touch screen.

Element transition to hover state on click is no intuitive on touch screen.

For example: "Accept" button color Transform from grey to green. (How the use supposed to know the button is clickable?).

**Substitutes:**

You can trigger animation when element enter view, 
here is a link to how implement: [How can I tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

or

leave it with active hover state on mobile.